# I was installing ubuntu and this happened

Tags: kernel, caching

[image]

I'm installing ubuntu into an old computer. Everything was going great, I was in the installination phase, I got to the part where it asked me for what I would like to name this computer and then this came up. I don't know a lot about computers, but it doesn't look good. And now even if i reboot my pc, I find that windows is uninstalled, which I wanted to happen, but I thought I was getting something better instead. Can someone help me out thanks.
This is a picture of the screen as it stands right now.

Comment: Very odd. Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867591/how-to-solve-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-without-er . Try booting the live Ubuntu DVD/USB with "custom options" (I think you press F6 at boot time to add them) and append `selinux=0` to the end of the boot prompt. Then boot into the installer again.